# Check if list is made up by numbers only - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I need to write a predicate that returns true if a given list contains only numbers in Prolog. Example:

```
?- isDigit(['1', '2', '3']).
true
```

This is the code I've made so far:

```
isDigit(X) :-  digit(X).
isDigit([X | Xs]) :- digit(X), isDigit(Xs).

digit(1).
digit(2).
digit(3).
digit(4).
digit(5).
digit(6).
digit(7).
digit(8).
digit(9).
digit(0).
```

It returns false every time and i don't get the reason why.

Thank you

Comment: Dear Francesco, could you please show us your current attempt and describe where you are stuck?

Comment: I've added my code and where i'm stuck. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues with your code. First:

```
isDigit(X) :-  digit(X).
```

In your case the argument of `isDigit/1` is a list, and you want to ask for the elements of this list. For handling the only element of a list write it like this:

```
isDigit([X]) :-  digit(X).
```

Second: `1` and `'1'` are different. Try this as query:

```
?- isDigit([1, 2, 3]).
```

Tested with SWISH.